# Webpack + Babel: ReferenceError: {My class} is not defined

Tags: javascript, firefox, webpack, babeljs, package.json

I am newbie in development with Webpack and Babel.

I created a JS class for example:

```
export default class Log4js {

    #current_appender; 
}
```

When I try to create a js variable of my class in Firefox browser console, I got the following error:

> ```
> ReferenceError: Log4js is not defined [ ... ]
>   < ... > http://localhost:8080/:11
> ```

This is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

//Webpack configuration
const webpack_config = {

    //entrypoint
    entry: './src/Log4js.js',

    //Developemnt mode
    mode: 'development',

    //Path tu bundle
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './libs/bundle'),
        filename: 'log4js.js'
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [],
};

//Export webpack config
module.exports = webpack_config;
```

My `"package.json"` file:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-babel-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0"
  }
}
```

And my `".babelrc"` field:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Firefox version: 77.0.1;

My html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello world!</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="log4js.js" type="module"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var LOGGER = new log4js();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried:

1. import webpack bundle with `{type="module"}` in `<script>` tag;
2. Use `"export"` and `"export default"` in "log4js.js" class definition;
3. Use `"import"` statement in `<script>` tag in html file;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to expose functionality from your bundle then you need to output as a library:

```js
// webpack.config.js

output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, './libs/bundle'),
  filename: 'log4js.js'
  library: 'Log4js' // <-- ADD THIS
},
```

You should then be able to reference `Log4js` in other scripts.

You can fid the docs here for more options:
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary

Comment: Thank you! I added {library} and {libraryTarget} properties and axpose my library.